# [TFS 2015]: Migrate users from one AD domain to another

Tags: tfs-2015

We are planning to migrate users from our company domain (domainA) to our parent company's domain (domainB).   The login IDs for the users are going to change from domainA\firstname.lastname to domainB\employee#

For now, the TFS servers will reside in domainA.

What would be the best way to migrate our TFS users and still ensure that they still maintain their current permissions?

I did find this document regarding the Identities command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains

thanks

Comment: Did you also want to move the Team Foundation Server from domainA to domainB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to migrate accounts across domains in Active Directory and keep the TFS sever reside in domain A.

You could use [**TFSConfig Identities**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#identities) command  which lists or changes the security identifier (SID) of users and groups in your deployment of TFS.

Fist of all, there should has the **trust-relationship** between your two domains. Then follow below steps:

- Create all the new accounts on the new domain and **DON’T ADD THEM TO
  TFS**
- Open the command line as admin and navigate to “`C:Program
  FilesMicrosoft Team Foundation Server 14.0Tools`“
- Run the TFSConfig Identities with the right parameters such as

  `TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:Domain1 /todomain:Domain2 /account:OldAccount /toaccount:NewAccount`
- Review the result
- Force synchronization for fasting the retrieving the result or wait
  the synchronization to happen after sometimes

*Note: Once a user account is present in TFS, it cannot be removed or have another account mapped to it. For example, if you are moving DomainA/UserA to DomainB/UserB, the Identities command would only work to migrate the user if DomainB/UserB is not already present in TFS.*

More detail steps please refer this [tutorial](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/04/05/migrating-tfs-server-or-collection-to-another-domain/).

If you also want to move a Team Foundation Server installation from one domain to another, you need to follow the instructions exactly: [Move Team Foundation Server from one environment to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains)

---

***Update from OP:***

To prevent migrated users from reverting back to previous account, I had to make sure that they **weren't part of any domainA groups**.Once removed, I ran the following:

```
TFSServiceControl quiesce TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:OldDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName /account:OldAccountName /toaccount:NewAccountName TFSServiceControl unquiesce
```

I then ran a poweshell script that forced AD sync with TFS :

```
 [Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

 # connect to the server 
  $credProvider = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.UICredentialsProvider $tfsConnection = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServer "localhost:8080/tfs";, $credProvider $tfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()

 # force a full sync on the next sync execution. 
  $tfRegistry = $tfsConnection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamFoundationRegistry]) $tfRegistry.SetValue('/Service/Integration/Settings/IdentitySyncFull', $true)

# Kick the IMS periodic job so that it syncs. 
  $jobIds = [Guid[]] @('544DD581-F72A-45A9-8DE0-8CD3A5F29DFE') $jobSvc = $tfsConnection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamFoundationJobService]) $jobSvc.QueueJobsNow($jobIds, $true)
```

Comment: Yes, according to the article that I linked, I can use TFSConfig Identities to batch process the accounts IF the user name stayed the same.  In our case, user name is changing from firstname.lastname to employeeIDNumber so I guess I'll need to manually move the SIDs too?        I did find this in the link:   "If you're new domain contains one or more identities where the name changes between environments, you'll need to manually update the SIDs for each of those identities."

Comment: @SRX Yes, you are right. Sorry about this, you could not do this in batch process. For every account that has this requirement in DomainB, you need to type the following command:  `TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:OldDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName /account:OldAccountName /toaccount:NewAccountName` one by one.

Comment: Hello Patrick -   I did update one user account.  It seems the changes took but then reverted back after 20 minutes or so.  The Matches column showed false, so I assume the SID didn't synchronize.    In the migration steps I jumped straight to moving the identities.   We are keeping TFS server in domainA, while only user accounts are being converted over to domainB.   Is this even possible or do we have to move server to new domain first, and then upgrade user accounts?

Comment: @SRX it's supported, you could take a look at this part:`The Identities command lists or changes the security identifier (SID) of users and groups in your deployment of TFS. You might need to change or update the SID for users and groups in one of the following scenarios: migrating accounts across domains in Active Directory` .  When you change the account  the target account or accounts must already in windows. Do you make sure there are correspondingly accounts in Domain B.

Comment: @SRX Try to use tfsconfig identities, could you see both account  `DomianA\firstname.lastname` and `DomainB\employeeIDNumber`  exists = true. If so, seems  you may getting an "already exists" issue. There is no way to resolve this once you are in this situation as there are a bunch of assets associated with both identity's.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the employeeID account exists in domainB.  DomainA\firstname.lastname and DomainB\employeeID both have exists=true.     Its strange that when I convert it over, i can use domainB\employeeID for awhile with all permissions intact. but then later on in the day, that account is removed and replaced back with domainA\FN.LN

Comment: @SRX Sorry for later reply due to holiday. According to your description and exists=true, seems the domainB\employeeID has already added to TFS server. Take a look at this question, you may encountered a similar issue. [Why can't I change the identity of this account in Team Foundation Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096622/why-cant-i-change-the-identity-of-this-account-in-team-foundation-server) Try to use  an account `domainB\xxx` which already added in the domain, but not added to TFS server. And then use  `TFSConfig Identities /change xx` command.

Comment: @SRX Moreover, if the issue still exists, you could also try to also move the Team Foundation Server installation from domainA to domainB, which may do the trick. And this also makes it easier to manage.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I just wanted to update this in case others have similar issues.   To prevent migrated users from reverting back to previous account, I had to make sure that they weren't part of any domainA groups.  Once removed, I ran the following:   TFSServiceControl quiesce
TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:OldDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName /account:OldAccountName /toaccount:NewAccountName
TFSServiceControl unquiesce                                                                                       I then ran a poweshell script that forced AD sync with TFS

Comment: This is the powershell script (broken down due to character limitation here).                                                                                                                          [Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

Comment: # connect to the server
$credProvider = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.UICredentialsProvider
$tfsConnection = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServer "http://localhost:8080/tfs",  
$credProvider
$tfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()                                                                     # force a full sync on the next sync execution.
$tfRegistry = $tfsConnection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamFoundationRegistry])
$tfRegistry.SetValue('/Service/Integration/Settings/IdentitySyncFull', $true)

Comment: # Kick the IMS periodic job so that it syncs.
$jobIds = [Guid[]] @('544DD581-F72A-45A9-8DE0-8CD3A5F29DFE')
$jobSvc = $tfsConnection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamFoundationJobService])
$jobSvc.QueueJobsNow($jobIds, $true)

Answer (score 0):

This question is several years old, but lacking any proper documentation on how to do this, we stumbled upon this thread trying to prepare our own migration.

First thing to be said: The answer provided by @PatrickLu-MSFT still works on Azure DevOps Server 2019, the hint that user accounts must not be added to the Azure DevOps Server by AD groups saved me lots of time.

I still got one addition:
The user migration worked for all user accounts but mine. The reason: my old AD account was still a Windows admin on the Azure DevOps Server itself. And by default, all admin accounts are automatically added to the Admins-Group in the Azure DevOps Server.
This took me quite a while to figure out, my user got migrated back automatically all the time.

Additionally, after our batch-migration, all AD user accounts had lost their permissions. I did some individual test runs up front, they all worked perfectly, so it took me about half an hour to figure out why nobody was able to log in. Make sure to check the permissions and Azure DevOps Server group memberships after the migration!

The Powershell script didn't work anymore, so I transferred it into a simple c# program using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient nuget packages:

```
var credProvider = new VssClientCredentials();
var tfsConnection = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri(AdsForceAuthSync.Default.TfsUrl), credProvider);
tfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated();

var tfsRegistry = tfsConnection.GetService<ITeamFoundationRegistry>();
tfsRegistry.SetValue("/Service/Integration/Settings/IdentitySyncFull", $"true");
var jobSvc = tfsConnection.GetService<ITeamFoundationJobService>();
jobSvc.QueueJobNow(Guid.Parse("544dd581-f72a-45a9-8de0-8cd3a5f29dfe"), true);
```

Note that this program requires authentication, so a user with admin permissions should already be migrated or temporarily created.

So in short:

1. replace the AD groups in the Azure DevOps UI by individual user accounts and remove all the groups
2. make sure, no account of the target AD is added to the Azure DevOps Server. If so, you can delete the new AD accounts from the SQL database (table Identities in the Configuration-DB). This was absolutely sufficient in our case.
3. Make sure, none of the users to migrate is a windows admin on the Azure DevOps Server, also remove it from the admin console. By now the AD user should have a new account in the new AD - simply replace the admins manually.
4. run the `TFSServiceControl quiesce` command (in the tools directory of the Azure DevOps Server installation). This will shut down all services, so nobody will be able to access the Azure DevOps Server anymore.
5. migrate the users `TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:OldDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName /account:OldAccountName /toaccount:NewAccountName`. Omitting  the /account and /toaccount parameters will do a batch migration of all AD users.
6. restart the services `TFSServiceControl unquiesce`
7. kick the AD sync of the Azure DevOps Server
8. check the group memberships of the migrated users