# TFS users migrated to new domain; accounts in TFS reports not updated

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We recently migrated users to a new domain using this command:

```
TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:Domain1 /todomain:Domain2 /account:OldAccount /toaccount:NewAccount
```

Accessing TFS appears to be fine for the users, however, the folder security in TFS reports don't show that the users updated.  There must be a separate process for this since reports exists out on the SQl database server?

```
http://<SQLSERVER>/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTfsReports%2fDefaultCollection
```

Comment: Have you followed this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains?

Comment: Hello Cece.  Yes, I did reference that doc.  We only migrated the end users to new domain.  The service accounts and servers reside in old domain.  My original thread on that is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151311/tfs-2015-migrate-users-from-one-ad-domain-to-another/48162665?noredirect=1#comment83507690_48162665

Answer (score 0):

You could try the items below:

1. Run the following command to update the service account:

`TFSConfig Accounts /change /AccountType:ApplicationTier /account:AccountName /password:Password`

2. Run the following command to update the data source account used for reporting:

`TFSConfig Accounts /change /AccountType:ReportingDataSource /account:AccountName /password:Password`

3. Re-configure Reporting and Analysis Services in Administration Console.
4. Restart TFS services. On the TFS application-tier computer, open a Command Prompt window with administrative permissions and change directories to Drive:\%programfiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools, and type the following TFSServiceControl command:

`TFSServiceControl unquiesce`

5. Re-start TFS server.

Comment: Service account didn't migrate, so I don't think there's a need to update that (yet).  Data source account also was not migrated and resides on old domain.   End user accounts in TFS reports are still pointing to old domain.

Comment: Are you able to add uer with new domain in Folder setting? Have you restarted TFS server?